# Clearfix with absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css, positioning, clearfix

My problem is the following:
The border does not wrap the containing items. I know this is because I position the content-item absolute, but I need them to be absolute for the layout to work. This also means that I cannot use the clearfix solution (this means that I have to float the elements, which it not an option).
So my question is, how to I get the parent div to get the height of the contained elements.

**EDIT: No Javascript solution, CSS only**

Html:

```
<div class="mask">
    <div id="content-1" class="content-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...
    </div>
    <div id="content-2" class="content-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...
    </div> 
</div>​​​​
```

CSS:

```
.mask{
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
.content-item{
    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
}
#content-1{
    left:10px;
}
#content-2{
   left: 300px;
}
```

​

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set one item to `float:left` and the other to `position:absolute; right:0` and use a `clearfix`.

Comment: This will only work if the floated element has a greater height than the one with the fixed position.

Comment: Also works with more than 2 items, just put 1 of them as float:left and the rest position:absolute

Answer (score 1):

Change the `position: absolute;` of `.content-item` to `position: relative;` and give it a `float: left;`. Remove `#content-1` and `#content-2`, you don't need them anymore. And at last insert a new class into your html (after the 2 `#content` id's) and add a `clear: both;` to that class in your stylescheet.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/xLTJp/1/

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you can't use position: relative;, my code is useless now